# JAXWS Socket Factory setting does not work

Tags: ssl, jakarta-ee, java-8, jax-ws

I am calling a SOAP Webservice with JAXWS, but the SSL Socket Factory does not work. Instead of using my trust- and keystore, the application uses the default truststore of the JRE.

```
BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) myWebservicePort;
Map<String, Object> requestContext = bindingProvider.getRequestContext();   
requestContext.put(JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sslSocketFactory);
```

Answer (score 0):

The constant `SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY` has a different value depending on the JAXWS implementation in use. The one in JDK 8 is in the class `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties`, whereas the reference implementation JAXWS-RI (provided e.g. by JakartaEE or other sources before JakartaEE took over from Oracle) has the same class in a different package: `com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties`.

So make sure you import the version of `JAXWSProperties` which has the `SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY` constant that matches your runtime.

FYI, the actual Strings are:

- JDK 8: `"com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory"`
- JAXWS-RI: `"com.sun.xml.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory"`

However, do not use them verbatim, rather pick the correct `JAXWSProperties` class.